# docker-compose can't connect to Docker daemon and sudo docker-compose up --build fails with standard_init_linux.go:211

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've been trying to create multiple containers using a `docker-compose.yml` file. However, `docker-compose up --build` returns

`Building my_service_1`

`ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localunixsocket - is it running?`

`If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.`

Once I push through that using `sudo docker-compose up --build` I get

```
Building my_service_1
Step 1/21 : FROM multiarch/qemu-user-static:x86_64-aarch64 as qemu
---> 1e35a4c44a72
Step 2/21 : FROM arm64v8/alpine:3.12.0
---> 62ee0e9f8440
Step 3/21 : COPY --from=qemu /usr/bin/qemu-aarch64-static /usr/bin/
---> Using cache
---> d46618368989
Step 4/21 : USER root
---> Using cache
---> adebfcffb716
Step 5/21 : RUN apk update
---> Running in 79d047cbbc54
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
ERROR: Service 'my_service_1' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apk update' returned a 
non-zero code: 1
```

This is the first few lines of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM multiarch/qemu-user-static:x86_64-aarch64 as qemu
FROM arm64v8/alpine:3.12.0
COPY --from=qemu /usr/bin/qemu-aarch64-static /usr/bin/
USER root
RUN apk update
RUN apk upgrade
```

and this is my `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
version: '2'
services:
  my_service_1:
    hostname: service1
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.24.2
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:9000:9000
    entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'cd / && /opt/router/router 2 9000 `hostname`'"
  my_service_2:
    hostname: service2
    build:
      context: .
      args:
    - SERVICE1_ENDPOINT=192.168.24.2:9000
depends_on:
  - my_service_1
networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.24.0/24
          gateway: 192.168.24.1
```

Comment: Looks like you need to setup arm emulation on your x86_64 based os. First link I found without too much digging around => https://www.stereolabs.com/docs/docker/building-arm-container-on-x86/ Your error message is exactly what is presented in this link as "First, let’s see what happens before setting up the emulation when trying to execute a program compiled for a different architecture"

Comment: @Zeitounator I was under the impression that I had the `qemu` packages installed and didn't even check if that was the case. I got another error but I have to figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: Other note: rather than executing docker(-compose) as root, you should add your regular user to the `docker` group.

Comment: @Zeitounator To avoid the all the permission issues?

Comment: exactly. `sudo usermod -a -G docker youruser`. Then you will be able to use docker command which access the docker local socket. Don't forget to logout/in after that for new permissions to be effective.